# How to use karyotype notation?

Tags: genetics, karyotype

I'm looking at two karyotypes, one for a person with Klinefelter's Syndrome and another with Patau's. What is the karyotype notation for them? I don't understand what I looked up online. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: At a minimum, posting the notation that you found when you looked them up would be helpful.